# An infinite simple group has no proper subgroup of finite index.

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ a  simple group such that $|G|>n$ for every positive integer $n$. Show that $G$ has no proper subgroups of finite index.

Comment: You are supposed to ask questions, not issue commands.

Answer (score 7):

> If a group has a proper subgroup of index $k$, then it has a normal subgroup of index at most $k!$.

Let $H \le G$ have index $k > 1$. Consider the action of $G$ on the right cosets of $H$. This yields a homomorphism $\varphi : G \to S_{k}$. By the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem), $\ker(\varphi)$ has index at most $\lvert S_{k} \rvert = k!$ in $G$.

Comment: Hello. Why did you consider the action over the right cosets? Wouldn’t this work if we take the action over the left cosets?

Comment: Doesn't the first isomorphism theorem only apply if the homomorphism is surjective? How do we know that $\phi$ is surjective? Also, $H$ will always have the trivial normal subgroup, which has order less than $k!$, so why is this a contradiction?