# Prove/disprove: Let $G$ a simple infinite group $\implies$ $G$ doesn't have a proper subgroup of finite index.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

**I'm writing this question for proof verification and also since I didn't find the already existing answers very clear:**

[If $G$ is an inﬁnite simple group then any proper subgroup of $G$ has inﬁnite index.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414099/if-g-is-an-in%ef%ac%81nite-simple-group-then-any-proper-subgroup-of-g-has-in%ef%ac%81nite-in?rq=1)

[An infinite simple group has no proper subgroup of finite index.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083590/an-infinite-simple-group-has-no-proper-subgroup-of-finite-index)

---

**Here's my proof:**

By contradiction assume exists $H \le G$ of finite index $\implies\; \exists: 1 \lt m \in \mathbf N$, such that $[G:H]={|G| \over |H|}=m$.

Take X to be the group of left cosets of $H$ in $G$: $\;G/H$.

Let us observe the action $G \mapsto G/H$ by multiplication from the left implementing we have $g.x = gx, \forall g \in G, \forall \;aH \in G/H$.

In particular let us observe the induced homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_m$.

Denote we have: $g \in Ker\phi \iff \phi(g) = Id_{G/H} \iff g \in H$, thus implementing we have Ker$\phi \neq \{e\}$.

From the first Iso theorem we have Ker$\phi \lhd G$ and since we saw Ker$\phi$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ we have contradiction to the assumption G is simple.

Comment: It is incorrect, $X$ is not a group.

Comment: It is unclear how is your $\phi$ defined. you even not say what is $\phi(g)=?$

Comment: @MathFail I used this as reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494207/if-h-leq-g-is-of-finite-index-then-we-have-a-normal-subgroup-n-leq-g-of-fi?rq=1, would you mind explaining what I did wrong?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: You have still not edited to deal with @MathFail 's first comment. You must not say that $X$ is a group, it is a set. You do prove that $\ker\phi \leqslant H$ but that by itself does not make $\ker\phi\ne e$, you need to prove that $|G:\ker\phi|$ divides $m!$ and so $\ker\phi\ne e$. All this is set out in the solutions that you reference.

Comment: You cannot write $[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ when they are infinite. There is no division on infinite cardinals. So your second sentence is already nonsensical.

Comment: (More minor is that the grammar is incorrect. The symbol $\Rightarrow$ is usually pronounced "implies". So your subject line says "Let $G$ a simple infinite group implies $H$ doesn't have...". The premise is not your imperative to the reader to make $G$ denote an infinite simple group. The antecedent to the $\implies$ shouldn't be an instruction to the reader, it should be a declaratory sentence about the group $G$, just like the consequent is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is going in the correct direction, but I found four important issues, with (3) and (4) being the main ones:

1. You write $gx$, but this is not defined (I understand what you mean, but this is still an issue).
2. I am uncomfortable with the line "In particular, let us observe the induced homomorphism $\phi:G\to S_m$"; tell me why it exists, rather than state that it does!
3. Your proof "shows" that $H=\ker\phi$, which is **incorrect** as $H$ may not be normal in $G$. (This is the line starting "Denote we have".) If we dig into your proof, we have: $g\in\ker\phi$ if and only if $gaH=aH$ for all $aH\in G/H$, which is equivalent to $a^{-1}ga\in H$ for all $a\in G$. Therefore, $\ker\phi$ is the largest normal subgroup contained in $H$. But, as just noted, $H$ may not be normal.
4. At the end you state that $\ker\phi$ is proper, but this is never proven.

Below, I have copied-and-pasted your solution, and then edited it to address the issues discussed, and also to make some bits slightly clearer.

---

Assume, seeking a contradiction, that $G$ is simple but that there exists $H \lneq G$ of finite index, i.e. $1\neq[G:H]=m<\infty$.

Let us observe the action $G \mapsto G/H$ by multiplication from the left implementing we have $g.aH = gaH, \forall g \in G, \forall \;aH \in G/H$.

This action permutes the cosets $G/H$, so we have an induced homomorphism $\phi: G \to \operatorname{Sym}(G/H)\cong S_m$. (We covered this in Theorem ???, Section ??? of the notes.)

The kernel is a proper subgroup: As $H\lneq G$, there exists some $g\in G\setminus H$. The action of $g$ on $G/H$ is non-trivial, and so $g\not\in\ker\phi$.

The kernel is non-trivial: As $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is finite, the kernel has finite index in the infinite group $G$, and hence also contained infinitely many elements. In particular, it is non-trivial.

From the First Isomorphism Theorem, we have $\ker\phi \lhd G$ and since we saw $\ker\phi$ is a proper, non-trivial subgroup of $G$ we have contradiction to the assumption G is simple.

---

Let me finish with proof-structural point: it is not contradiction but contrapositive which you are using here. That is, you are proving that if $G$ has a finite index subgroup then it is not simple. Phrasing this as a contradiction is not incorrect, but is slightly clunky.

Comment: thank you this is a great help and I really appreciate it especially all that is wrong in my proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your solution by not taking the long-winded route of referring to Cayley's theorem.

Let $G$ be a simple infinite group. Simple means that it does not have any proper normal subgroup.

Assume that $\emptyset\neq H\leq G$ has finite index.

$\implies \{gH:g\in G\}$ has only $n$ elements in it for some natural number $n$.

$\implies$ $G/H$ is finite with order $n$.

As mentioned in the comments, this does not mean that $|G|/|H|=n$ since $G$ is infinite.

Consider the canonical map $\phi:G\rightarrow G/H$ that acts as $g\mapsto  gH$.
Do you see that this is a group homomorphism?

(**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, this is not a group  homomorphism since $G/H$ need not be a group. This can be solved by replacing $H$ with another subgroup $N$ which is normal. The existence of this uses group action. user1729's answer is better as it is straight forward.)

Since the codomain is finite and the domain is infinite, $\phi$ has a non-trivial kernel.

By the first isomorphism theorem, $\ker\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, contradicting the simplicity of $G$.

Comment: This doesn't work. Your map $\phi$ is only a group homomorphism if $H$ is normal in $G$, as $G/H$ does not in general have a group structure. (This is basically the first comment to the question -- $X=G/H$ is not a group.)

Comment: @user1729 You are right. I will let my answer be so that others learn from my mistake.